# Add timestamps to dokku/heroku git push output

Tags: shell, output-redirect

I am trying to "profile" from the command line how much time a dokku/heroku push deploy takes.  I would like to add a relative timestamp to each line in the output of `git push`.

Using `ts` from moreutils does not work - it adds prints randomly:

```
git push dokku main 2>&1 | ts -s
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: probably `stdbuf -oL`

Comment: @KamilCuk: I tried many variations of `stdbuf` witthout luck.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the server is sending ANSI escape characters that deletes the output created by `ts`!

```
sed 's/\x1b\[1G\x1b\[K//g'
```

Solves this issue.